# How i should pass the "public static final By " type value as a parameter.Below sample code

Tags: java, selenium

this class I am storing the XPath and saving as public static final By type variable.

```
class page { 
    public static final By signInTab = By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')][1]"); 
    public static final By emailAddress = By.id("login");
}
```

I am going to run this class with testing and this is a sample code the main moto is to get the XPath from page class and pass it in a webdriverUtillfuncalss class

```
class stepdefinations { 
    //creating the object of webdriver class and using different method to perform webdriver operations 
    webdriverUtillfuncalss lib=new webdriverUtillfuncalss(); 
    //please conform whether its correct to pass it here 
    lib.mouseHovertoElement(page.emailAddress);

}
```

I have doubt that this can be wrong way of passing it, please suggest

```
class webdriverUtillfuncalss {
    public void mouseHovertoElement(By element) {
        Actions mouseho=new Actions(driver);
        mouseho.moveToElement(driver.findElement(element)).build().perform();
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't, just access it by: page.xpath; also: it would serve you well to read up on naming conventions

Comment: Thanks for your answer that way its working but  this is the new framework i am using and modifying it where i can use in stepdefination class --driver.findelement(page.emailaddress)  --> this is working but again i dont want to use driver in stepdefination class and keeping all driver methods in another class-> webdriverUtillfuncalss there i need to pass -->page.emailaddress and i am not able to do it.

Comment: since they are declared final, how exactly do you "modify" it?

Comment: I mean to modify the existing framework,Not modifying the final variable

Comment: what framework are you talking about, and why would you want to alter a framework you're working with?

Comment: _i dont want to use driver in stepdefination class_ In the code snippet you provided driver is not used in `stepdefinations `. It is unclear what you are asking. You should edit your question and point out what you expect your code to do and what it actually does.

Comment: I have started working on cucumber framework.All steps definition of feature will be written in steps_definition class.

Comment: I have started working on cucumber framework.All steps definition of feature will be written in steps_definition class. Now in my current project we are planning to implement the framework and the challenge is if we write  all driver operation in step definition class it will be big in size and will contain duplicate code so we are planning to keep all driver related methods ,for Example     ->driver.findelement(by.xpath())   .,,    driver.findelement(by.xpath()) .click  ,,      driver.findelement(by.xpath()).sendkeys() ,etc in one class

Answer (score 0):

My understanding.
1) Driver object creation is in Stepdefinition
2) All the driver function like wait,click,sendkeys etc in webdriverUtillfuncalss

Another Way is Make the methods in webdriverUtillfuncalss as static . So you need not to create webdriverUtillfuncalss object. Also send the driver object as argument to every method in webdriverUtillfuncalss.

Comment: Agree,But i have one hiccup here  

1) I have my xpath in page classes as --public static final By signInTab = By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')][1]"); 

2) In step definition I am calling page class and accessing it like Pageclass.xpath ,now i have to pass  this->Pageclass.xpath as parameter to webdriverUtillfuncalss.

Comment: Then Use getter methods from Page class to pass it to wedriverutilfuncclass.